# evil text objects for code object at point?

Tags: evil, code, evil-text-object

I use text objects with evil like "i(" for the contents of the brackets. I would quite like "magic code aware text objects"?

This textobject would:

- return the entire function if I was at a function
- return the entire class if I was at a class
- return the switch if I was at an "if/elif" block

etc.

Is there a way to do this task that does not consist of completely implementing it myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be https://github.com/meain/evil-textobj-tree-sitter can fit your need.

Take a look at Doom Emacs' [tree-sitter module config](https://github.com/doomemacs/doomemacs/blob/9d4d5b756a8598c4b5c842e9f1f33148af2af8fd/modules/tools/tree-sitter/config.el#L40) for examples.

But if you need something so DWIMmy instead of vi's preferred explicit approach, IMO [tree-sitter & expand-region : tree-sitter-mark-bigger-node](https://github.com/emacs-tree-sitter/elisp-tree-sitter/issues/20) should be more appropriate for you.

Comment: That very much looks like what I am after thanks.